# using php and javascript I want to feed in a decimal value and increment it by one every 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, php

I have created this script, which seems to feed in the value, but does not update.  When I view the source code created, the var elapsedtime is updated with the value, but it is not being updated every minute.

```
<?php
$elapsedtime = $database->calcProdtime($client,$stage,$orderid);

     ...

echo "<tr><td class=tablarge>Elapsed Time: </td><td class=tablarge><span id='ct' ></span>".$elapsedtime." minutes</td></tr>";

    ...
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function display_c(){
        var refresh=60000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
        <?php echo "var elapsedtime = ".$elapsedtime; ?>        
        mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
   }

   function display_ct() {
        var strcount
        elapsedtime++
        document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
        tt=display_c();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: If you just want the time to update, do it on the client side. Try cuteTime.js

Comment: I am incrementing by a minute each minute, but want to start from a given number, being the time already spent on this process, which I feed in using the elapsedtime variable.

Comment: How are you activating the javascript function to update the time?

Comment: With this.

<body onload=display_ct();>.  I originally got the code from something that updated the current time,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleaner one: http://plnkr.co/edit/JLyC7Lf0FcfALCwpWF3M?p=preview

```
<h1>Elapsed time <span id='elapsed-time'>150</span></h1>
<!--<h1>Elapsed time <span id='elapsed-time'><?=$elapsed_time?></span></h1>-->
<script>
  setInterval( function(){
    var elapsed_time = parseInt( document.getElementById('elapsed-time').innerHTML );
    elapsed_time = elapsed_time + 1;
    document.getElementById('elapsed-time').innerHTML = elapsed_time;
  }
  , 1 * 1000);// Refresh rate in milli seconds
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know if this is the best answer but it was the first one I got, and with a little tweaking I got it to do just what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Brotheyura is right

```
<?php echo "var elapsedtime = ".$elapsedtime; ?>
```

has to be moved out of the function, so elapsedtime is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   <?php echo "var elapsedtime = ".$elapsedtime; ?>        
   function display_c(){
        var refresh=60000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds

        mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
   }

   function display_ct() {
        var strcount
        elapsedtime++
        document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = 'x';
        tt=display_c();
   }
  display_c();
 </script>
```

Comment: Try adding some text explaining what you did. Code-only answers generally are not very helpful.

Comment: Also, you're wrapping `'x'` with single quotes.

Comment: This code after 60sec put some data in id='ct' and increments the variable elapsedtime per unit

Answer (score 0):

The follow code works for me(Please notice I have just cut the php part and given the variable elapsedtime a initialize value to simplify the experience)

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='example.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class=tablarge>Elapsed Time: </td>
                <td class=tablarge>
                    <span id='ct' ></span>
                    minutes
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

example.js file:

```
var elapsedtime = 100;
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
display_c();
function display_c(){
    mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
    var strcount;
    elapsedtime++;
    document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = elapsedtime;
    tt=display_c();
}
```

Some notice here

1. I have changed the refresh interval from 60000 in your code to 60 in my code, this will cause the  number displayed in the page to be refreshed once per second.
2. **Key point** there is you need to first trigger the **setTimeout** method by invoking **display_c()** manually for the first time, I didn't see such first time trigger in the javascript code you posted above.
3. I assume the content of span with id **ct** is where you would like to put the value of variable **elapsedtime**, so I have changed the code accordingly.
4. Also I am curious about the variable **strcount** since you defined it but didn't use it later.

You can just modify my code and combine it with your php code to make it work.

Comment: The delay is in milliseconds, so `60` means every 60 milliseconds. If you want (roughly) once per second, the delay should be 1000.

Comment: Thanksxxioxtrrdska